# C# How to convert date local to UTC with time 00:00:00 and 23:59:59?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I have a stored procedure which returns data between date range. I am sending Start Date and End Date as parameters after converting those dates into UTC. I am facing difficulty due to time span.

For example:

- StartDate: 2019-08-05T06:11:02.676Z
- EndDate: 2019-08-05T06:11:02.676Z

I can not get data for the day 5th of August.

For that I need datetime format like,

- StartDate: 2019-08-05T00:00:00
- EndDate: 2019-08-05T23:59:59

Please help me to derive above datetime format.

Comment: Do you want to convert the date to the format `2019-08-05T00:00:00` or you want a date string?

Comment: I want date in format => StartDate: 2019-08-05T00:00:00 & 
EndDate: 2019-08-05T23:59:59

Comment: `EndDate: 2019-08-05T23:59:59` Why do you need that? If you are doing some kind of filtering the standard solution is to use `EndDateExclusive` and set it to `2019-08-06`. Then use `< EndDateExclusive`. This avoids weird edge cases with milliseconds right at the end of the day.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just create two DateTimes objects with the time set, for example:

```
var now = DateTime.Now();
var startDate = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, 0, 0, 0);
var endDate = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, 23, 59, 59);
```

Comment: This will not catch any datetime entries between `endDate` and the start of the next date (e.g. those were the millisecond is set). I strongly suggest reading my earlier comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DateTime.Now.Date()` to get only `Date` and compare only dates.

```
var dateAndTime = DateTime.Now;
var date = dateAndTime.Date;
```